# Does Kyne's Peace work on all animals?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Does the Kyne's Peace shout work on everything, including mammoths, or are they limited to a certain level?  What does higher levels of the shout do?

Answer (score 6):

Kyne's Peace works on all animals *except for* Mammoths.

It has a maximum effective level of 20. Mammoths are level 38 according to the Prima Guide. The next highest level animals are Snow Bears, who are level 20, and are thus affected by the shout.

I've tested this against both, and those results seem to hold with no Illusion perks.

Haven't tested Illusion perks, but in theory they shouldn't change the result, as Hypnotic Gaze and Animage offer a combined +16 levels of effective targets, which would bring the maximum affected level to 36. Since Mammoths are level 38, they would remain unaffected.

Comment: Clearly, Mammoths just don't give a @#$*.

Answer (score 2):

According to [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Animal_Allegiance),

The only thing that changes with levels 2 and 3 of the shout are affected area and duration - it's the same maximum level of 20 at all 3 ranks.

It'd be interesting to see if Illusion perks enhanced it.

Comment: This only answers half the question.

Comment: It works on any animal which is level 20 or below. Until we get access to the construction kit, we won't know exact levels of mammoths, etc.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer AFAIK, Mammoths are level 35-40. (Giving grand souls or something)

Comment: @Communist duck, that's a very good point, since they're grand souls there's no way they're level 20 according to [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36778/how-do-i-know-what-type-of-soul-a-creature-has)