# What creatures fit into the different soul gem sizes?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I know what type of soul a creature has?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36778/how-do-i-know-what-type-of-soul-a-creature-has)

There are a few questions on soul gems and how they work or where to find them, but nothing on which creatures fit into which sizes of soul gems.

There are petty, lesser, common, greater and grand soul gems, as well as black soul gems.

So instead of me taking one of each gem and seeing what soul gets put into what gem, I'd like to get someone to tell me quickly which creatures can fill which soul gems.

Comment: Is this a dup of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36778/how-do-i-know-what-type-of-soul-a-creature-has ?

Comment: This is a similar question, i did not know there were another one, thank you for pointing that out, but no, not intentional to be a duplicate

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The rule of thumb when hunting animals is that:

- Any weak hostile animal or passive animal will go into a petty gem (rabbit, fox, goat, wolf, dog, chicken, mudcrab, slaughterfish, cow, elk, skeever).
- Any moderately powerful animal or rare passive animal will go into a lesser gem (sabre cat, horse, snow fox, pit wolf, ice wolf, charus).
- The strongest animals go into a common gem (bears, charus reapers)
- The very largest animal (mammoth) goes in a grand gem.

When fighting Draugr and the undead:

- The basic form (draugr, skeleton) goes in a petty gem.
- The slightly stronger forms (restless, wight) go in a lesser gem.
- The stronger forms (sourge, overlord) go in a common gem.
- The strongest forms (deathlord) goes in a greater gem.

When fighting Atronachs:

- Flame atronachs go in lesser gems.
- Frost atronachs go in common gems.
- Storm atronachs go in greater gems.

When fighting Skyrim's natural monsters:

- Trolls and spriggans go in lesser gems.
- Frost trolls and hagravens go in common gems.
- Giants and wispmothers go in greater gems.

When fighting Falmer:

- Most falmer (falmer, gloomlurker, skulker) go in lesser gems.
- Stronger falmer (nightprowler, shadowmaster) go in common gems.

Dwemer constructs are machines, and as such do not have souls.

Grand gems are only needed for Ghosts and Mammoths, making fighting these creatures desirable for the best enchantments. They can also be used to capture "special" enemies, such as the Dragon Priests. Dragon souls are consumed by the Dragonborn; you cannot soul trap Dragons. Black soul gems are used for capturing the souls of creatures normally protected by Arkay - NPCs of any of the playable races. Their souls are of "Grand" size, making them also desirable for the best enchantments. Soul gem fragments are broken soul gems, and are not useful for anything.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the soul gem fragments.  I've been wondering if there was some way to put those together, or if I should just ditch them.

Comment: Where do bandits fit in?

Comment: Bandits, Vampires, Forsworn and NPCs are all protected by Arkay, and so must be stored in Black Soul Gems.

Comment: @Thaumajig It may be worth noting that although you can't soul trap  Dwemer constructs, most (if not all, haven't investigated) will drop an appropriately-filled soul gem when killed. E.g. Centurions drop greater (or grand, not sure) gems whereas Spiders drop petty gems.

Comment: is there any mod that should such information? to all entities?

Answer (score 16):

Checkout the [Skyrim wiki page on souls](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Souls) for a list.

- Alpha Wolf   **Petty**
- Bear     **Common**
- Cave Bear    **Common**
- Chaurus Reaper   **Common**
- Chaurus  **Lesser**
- Chicken  **Petty**
- Corrupted Shade  LeveledL:1x, **Petty**
- Cow  **Petty**
- Deer     **Petty**
- Dog  **Petty**
- Dragon Priest    **Grand**
- Draugr Death Overlord    **Greater, Grand**
- Draugr Deathlord     **Common, Greater, Grand**
- Draugr Overlord  **Common**
- Draugr Restless  **Lesser**
- Draugr Scourge Lord  **Common**
- Draugr Scourge   **Common**
- Draugr Thrall    **Petty**
- Draugr Wight     **Lesser**
- Draugr   **Petty**
- Dremora Kynreeve     **Grand (Black)**
- Dwarven Centurion    **N.D.**
- Dwarven Sphere   **N.D.**
- Dwarven Spider Worker    **N.D.**
- Elk  **Petty**
- Falmer Gloomlurker   **Lesser**
- Falmer Nightprowler  **Common**
- Falmer Shadowmaster  **Common, Grand**
- Falmer Skulker   **Lesser**
- Falmer   **Lesser**
- Flame Atronach   **Lesser**
- Fox  **Petty**
- Frost Atronach   **Common**
- Frost Troll  **Common**
- Frostbite Spider     **Petty, Lesser**
- Ghost    **Grand**
- Giant Frostbite Spider   **Lesser**
- Giant    **Greater**
- Goat     **Petty**
- Hagraven     **Common**
- Hawk     **N.D.**
- Horker   **Petty**
- Horse    **Lesser**
- Ice Wolf     **Lesser**
- Ice Wraith   **Lesser**
- King Olaf One-Eye    **Grand**
- Magic Anomaly    LeveledL:1.75x
- Mammoth  **Grand**
- Mudcrab  **Petty**
- Potema's Remains     **Grand**
- Pit Wolf     **Lesser**
- Rabbit   **Petty**
- Red Eagle    **LeveledL:Special**
- Restless Draugr  **Lesser**
- Sabre Cat    **Lesser**
- Skeever  **Petty**
- Skeleton     **Petty**
- Slaughterfish    **Petty**
- Snow Bear    **Common**
- Snow Fox     **Lesser**
- Snowy Sabre Cat  **Lesser**
- Spriggan Matron  **Common**
- Spriggan     **Lesser**
- Storm Atronach   **Greater**
- The Pale Lady    **Greater**
- Troll    **Lesser**
- Udefrykte    **N.D.**
- Werewolf     **Lesser**
- Wispmother   **Greater**
- Wisp     **N.D.**
- Wolf     **Petty**
- Wounded Frostbite Spider     **Lesser**

Answer (score 5):

I believe it's like this:

Petty soul gem = creature souls below level 4.

Lesser soul gem = creature souls below level 16.

Common soul gem = creature souls below level 28.

Greater soul gem = creature souls below level 38,

Grand soul gem = any creature soul.

Black soul gem = any humanoid (e.g., bandits, elves, orcs, basically all NPCs) soul.

Comment: Was going to post the same. I think the only thing worth adding is the possibly ambiguous edge cases. Falmer, while descended from elves, are apparently sufficiently removed from that heritage to be considered creatures. Vampires, however, require a Black Soul Gem. Dragon souls, of course, can't be captured in soul gems.

Comment: @Bryan I think becuase they are *de-evolved* forms of Snow Elves and basically Dwemer slaves that they are considered *lesser* souls. See: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Falmer:_A_Study